# SocketTimeOutException with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, timeout, expo

I tried to test my first app on my Android phone, but after scanning, I receive the following error message:

" Uncaught error: java.error.sockettimeoutexception: failed to connect to 192.xxx.x.xx (port 19000) from 192.xxx.x.xx (port 45513) after 10000ms "

I already tried to open the firewall settings for port 19000, but that does not seem to be the problem, because it is not fixing my problem. I also closed the virtual network from virtualbox.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have a service running at 192.168.1.50 (port 19000) ? What platform are you on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved my own problem:
I just needed to change my wifi settings from public to private in Windows. After changing this, it worked for me.

Comment: Additionally, React Native's [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) guide precise that it's a requirement to have the same wireless network for the computer and the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem: Just i disconnect my pc and my mobile of internet.
And after that my app was lanched in my device, then i reconnect them with the same internet to test my app.

Answer (score 1):

On the localhost - try to change the connection from LAN to Local.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem try:

1. Change your network profile to private.
2. Disable windows firewall or add new rule for port 19000.
3. If you have any antivirus software allow port 19000 as well.
4. Open cmd and enter `ipconfig`. You should see a list of your networks. Your network ip address (highlighted in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D1eB.png)) should match the one that expo showing on start up (highlighted in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNo7d.png)).
   If these ip addresses don't match together then try disabling all other networks form Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections, or you could try setting `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME={your_ipv4_ip_address}`. `your_ipv4_ip_address` in my case is `192.168.1.33` ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbqqb.png))
5. Increase your networks priority from Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > "Select your active network" > Properties > "double click" Internet Protocol Version 4 > Advanced > uncheck Automatic Metric and enter number 10 or higher in text field.
6. On Android phone go to Settings > Apps > Expo Go > in advanced section set "Apps that can appear on top" status to on.

An alternative solution that is much slower is choosing tunnel connection.